# Using controllers inside StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Normally we dispose all controllers in **StatefulWidget's** dispose method.

But how if we are using **StatelessWidget**? is this going to automatically disposed?

Or we should **never** use controllers/streams inside StatelessWidget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the *initState* and *dispose* methods in a stateless widget like the stateful widgets.

Yet, there are ways of using stateless widgets with resources that need to be allocated and disposed to avoid memory leaks. You can check out one of these packages:

- [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)
- [Flutter hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks)

There are examples provided on the page that will help you understand the packages better.

I would recommend learning **Providers** if you don't know already as it will open a lot of ways you can manage states in your application efficiently and in a clean way.

**Flutter Hooks** may be a bit confusing to understand at first but, if you are familiar with **useHooks** in React, it is similar.